# How to submit data to another form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, web

I have one form on one page and another on another website. How do i submit the data filled out on the first form to the other?

**This is the code i have.**

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Comments: <input type="text" name="comments"><br>
 
  <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
  <button type="submit" formaction="http://www.example.com/formresult.asp")>Submit to another Form</button>
</form>
```

Ok so i want  my users to fill out one form, but have the option to send to another form.

The reason i need this because i have different HELP DESK support teams. INSTEAD of a number of different contact forms on a lot of html pages in my directory, i want to just have the option to send to anyone of my HELP DESK support team from one form. ALL THE FORMS are the same, the PHP files are the same. The EMAIL addresses are the only thing different for each team member.

The OPTION to send to a URL is also helpful. I read it is called 'An absolute URL ' and 'A relative URL'  as Attribute Values, but i think i am coding it wrong, it will not work for me. 
***type="submit" formaction="http://www.example.com/form.php")>Submit to another Form***

If i can get some help by an example on the code i will need to do both of these actions - i can start to test my new gaming clan website live.

Thanks in advance

Please advise

Comment: `formaction` is exactly how you would submit to a different action.  Perhaps that errant ")" character is causing the problem?  When you press that button, what specifically happens?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: If you have different support teams, then you can most likely hire a developer. This is both unclear and too broad here. You need to try something here.

Comment: from action_page.php you need to redirect to the second page with the data in the url. And then on second page you need to retrieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this you have to change the attributes for action tag on each button click. I have change submit type in to button and placed a hidden input type as submit. hope this help you to move on.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="myForm">

First name:

<input type="text" name="fname">
<br>

Last name:
<input type="text" name="lname">
<br>
Comments:
<input type="text" name="comments">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" style="display:none;">
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('myForm').setAttribute('action','action_page.php'); javascript:document.getElementById('sub').click();">Submit</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('myForm').setAttribute('action','http://www.example.com/formresult.asp'); javascript:document.getElementById('sub').click();">Submit to another Form</button>
<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is in the

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
```

You should target it to your php like this:

```
 <form action="/http://www.example.com/formresult.asp" method="get">
```

Then on the receiver file you should type the handling of the results

Comment: This isn't the solution. OP wants "Submit" to submit to _action_page.php_ and "Submit to another form" to submit to _http://www.example.com/formresult.asp_. Your solution only replaces one type with the other.